# How to get last-accessed date and time of file in Go?

Tags: go, last-modified

Does anyone know how to check for a file access date and time? The function returns the modified date and time and I need something that compares the accessed date time to the current date and time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [os.Stat](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) to get a [FileInfo](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) struct which also contains the last access time (as well as the last modified and the last status change time).

```
info, err := os.Stat("example.txt")
if err != nil {
     // TODO: handle errors (e.g. file not found)
}
// info.Atime_ns now contains the last access time
// (in nanoseconds since the unix epoch)
```

After that, you can use [time.Nanoseconds](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Nanoseconds) to get the current time (also in nanoseconds since the unix epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC). To get the duration in nanoseconds, just subtract those two values:

```
duration := time.Nanoseconds() - info.Atime_ns
```

Comment: This hasn't been correct since Go 1.0. You can get atime in a non-portable way by looking into [`FileInfo`'s `Sys`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) field (the type of that depends on `GOOS`).

Comment: time.Nanoseconds() will not tell time since epoch. It just tells the offset wrt current second. Correct way is time.Now().Unix(), but this will give in seconds...

Comment: What about time.Now().UnixNano()

Comment: If you care about multi-platform, this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31735) has a helpful summary about syscall fields per platform.

Answer (score 9):

By casting `os.FileInfo` to `*syscall.Stat_t`:

```
package main

import ( "fmt"; "log"; "os"; "syscall"; "time" )

func main() {
    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        fileinfo, err := os.Stat(arg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        atime := fileinfo.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t).Atim
        fmt.Println(time.Unix(atime.Sec, atime.Nsec))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is os-specific

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, after the Stat you can also do

```
statinfo.ModTime()
```

Also you can use Format() on it, should you need it eg for a webserver

see https://gist.github.com/alexisrobert/982674

Comment: The question asks about *access* time, not mod-time.

Comment: I googled the question you answered, so this answer gets a +1 from me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### For windows

[syscall.Win32FileAttributeData](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0602e2cdbc4b42e90c453e6ae365ad5f13f61c92/src/syscall/types_windows.go#L446-L448)

```golang
info, _ := os.Stat("test.txt")
fileTime := info.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData).LastAccessTime
aTime := time.Unix(0, fileTime.Nanoseconds())
```

Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    info, _ := os.Stat("./test.txt")
    fileTime := info.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData).LastAccessTime
    // _ = info.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData).CreationTime
    // _ = info.Sys().(*syscall.Win32FileAttributeData).LastWriteTime
    fileAccessTime := time.Unix(0, fileTime.Nanoseconds())

    // Compare
    // t2, _ := time.Parse("2006/01/02 15:04:05 -07:00:00", "2023/02/08 13:18:00 +08:00:00")
    now := time.Now()
    log.Println(fileAccessTime)
    log.Println(now.Add(-20 * time.Minute))
    if fileAccessTime.After(now.Add(-20 * time.Minute)) {
        fmt.Println("You accessed this file 20 minutes ago.")
    }
}
```

### Linux

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303743/9935654)